# Getting specific data from a remote text file

Tags: remote-access

Let's say I have this really large file with data on it on a foreign server.
I need to access a specific set of data (let's say from digits 20 to 30), but this text file is *infinitely* large (theoretically).  Is there a way I can request these digits while not requesting every digit?

I'm given a URL, the position of the data that I need to get it from and the amount of data characters I need, if it helps.

Also, I can use any language/request system I would like!

Comment: not unless you also have access to the server and can write script on server that accepts the paging request, and sends back what you want.. real world example, a Database :)

Comment: Afraid not, I can't even get the text, it is incredibly large. @Shaunak

Comment: knowing that you have a HTTP server, where you need the data from, I am afraid there's no way to get what you want, UNLESS you can write that logic on the server. None, of the existing web-servers I know support this kind of file request..

Comment: Okay, fair enough!  Thanks for your input @Shaunak.  Should I delete the question?

Comment: nah, I would say let it stay, I would love to be proven wrong here :) ... its a interesting problem to solve..  +1